# Changing an item color of a LongListSelector or Listbox that is binded

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have been trying to change the color of a `TextBlock` in a `ListBox` that gets it's color from a binding.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="{Binding ItemColor, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}" Style="{StaticResource posttitle}" d:LayoutOverrides="Width"/>
```

Here's the converter which works during the initial render:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value == null)
        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

    Color colorValue = (Color)value;

    return new SolidColorBrush(colorValue);
}
```

During the SelectionChanged Event I assigned a new color to the item like this:

```
private void List_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var listbox = (LongListSelector)sender;

    if (listbox.SelectedItem == null)
        return;

    MyItem item = (MyItem)listbox.SelectedItem;

    if (item.Clicked)
    {
        // Change some value
        item.Clicked = true;
        item.ItemColor = new Color() { A = 0xFF, R = 0xBD, G = 0xB7, B = 0x6B };
    }
}
```

If I put a breakpoint and check the datacontext, I can see that the value in the source has changed but visually the `LongListSelector` is not changing the look. The binding is to an `ObservableCollection` and `ItemColor` does notify of the change.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Clearly the `ItemColor` isn't raising the `PropertyChanged` event. Post the source for the `MyItem` class.

Answer (score 0):

You have not given enough information, but based on the code you provided, it looks like when `item.ItemColor` is set, the PropertyChanged event for `ItemColor` is not being fired.

`MyItem` should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and call `PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ItemColor"))`.